# Inconstant column widths when Excel document is sent between computers

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office

An agency I am working with just recently upgraded to Windows 10  and also upgraded from Office 2010 to 2016. All machines have the same image This agency exports reports from SSRS into an Excel document. We have an in house macro that automatically edits and formats the report for publication. For some reason when the same excel document with the same report and formatted table is opened on a different computer, the column widths very. The column widths are set via hard coded values in the macro. This affects the presentation of their final publication and, although it is just barely off, it is unacceptable to their clients.

I have explored a few different possibilities. I first looked at the font and its size after the document was opened on the different machine. They are both the same. I then looked to see if resolution may play a role. Although changing the DPI settings appeared to change the column width values, the DPI settings are the same on all the machines. If the macro is run again on the same report the column widths turn out correctly.

I'm really not sure what else to check. Could someone give me some advice or point me in the right direction?

```
Sub FormatAppDeptLvl()
'Macro to format Long Bill Department Level report
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim lastCol As Integer
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, m As Integer, n As Integer, p As Integer, q As Integer
    Dim checktotal As String

    'Sheets.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Set wsSheet = Sheets("NewReport")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not wsSheet Is Nothing Then
        'Sheet1 exists
        Sheets("NewReport").Delete
        Sheets.Add().Name = "NewReport"
    Else
        'Sheet1 does not exist
        Sheets.Add().Name = "NewReport"
    End If

   Sheets("CLMAppropDept").Select
   With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
   End With
   With ActiveSheet
        lastCol = .Cells(lastRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With
   Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
   Selection.Copy

    'To unHighlight cells
    Cells(1, 1).Select

    Sheets("NewReport").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
    Selection.Locked = False
    Selection.FormulaHidden = True

    Call ColorTabs

    'Calculate last row and column
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ActiveSheet.Cells(lastRow, ActiveSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'Merge Title
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol)).Select
    Selection.Merge
    'Range("B1:G1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
        .MergeCells = True
    End With

    'Table dimensions : Rows Height
    ActiveSheet.Rows.RowHeight = 10
    Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, lastCol)).RowHeight = 12
    Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, lastCol)).RowHeight = 18
    Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).RowHeight = 10

    'Table dimensions : Column Width
    ActiveSheet.Columns.ColumnWidth = 11.86
    Range("A:A").ColumnWidth = 29.075

    'Table dimensions : Column Width
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For k = 2 To lastCol
       checkfund = Cells(2, k).Value
       If checkfund Like "TOTAL*" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 11   'Total
       End If
       If checkfund Like "GENERAL*" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 12.071432  'GF
       End If
       If checkfund Like "CASH*" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 12.0714275 'CF
       End If
       If checkfund Like "REAPPROPRIATED*" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 12.28422   'RF
       End If
       If checkfund Like "FEDERAL*" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 12.071425  'FF
       End If
       If checkfund Like "*FTE" Then
           Range(Cells(3, k), Cells(lastRow, k)).ColumnWidth = 7.425      'FTE
       End If
    Next k

    'Justify 1st column Left and Bottom
    Range(Cells(4, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter   'Bottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    'Justify right columns Rigth and Bottom
    Range(Cells(4, 2), Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter   'Bottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
        .MergeCells = False
    End With

    'Padding
    For j = 4 To lastRow
        'MsgBox "Cell Len =" & Len(Cells(j, 1).Value)
        If Len(Cells(j, 1).Value) > 41 And Len(Cells(j, 1).Value) <= 72 Then
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Select
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).RowHeight = 20  '25
            With Selection
                .WrapText = True
            End With
            Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, lastCol)).Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .WrapText = True
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
        ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1).Value) > 72 And Len(Cells(j, 1).Value) <= 108 Then
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Select
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).RowHeight = 30  '36
            With Selection
                .WrapText = True
            End With
            Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, lastCol)).Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .WrapText = True
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
        ElseIf Len(Cells(j, 1).Value) >= 109 Then
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).Select
            Range(Cells(j, 1), Cells(j, 1)).RowHeight = 40  '47
            With Selection
                .WrapText = True
            End With
            Range(Cells(j, 2), Cells(j, lastCol)).Select
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
                .WrapText = True
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
        End If
    Next j

    'Merging BREAKDOWN row
    lastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 3 To lastRow
       checktotal = Cells(i, 1).Value
       If checktotal Like "BREAKDOWN*" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, lastCol)).Select
        With Selection
            .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
            .WrapText = True
            .Orientation = 0
            .AddIndent = False
            .IndentLevel = 0
            .ShrinkToFit = False
            .ReadingOrder = xlLTR
            .MergeCells = True
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            .Rows.RowHeight = 15
        End With
        Selection.Merge
        Cells(i, 1).RowHeight = 10
       End If
    Next i

    Cells(lastRow + 2, 1).Select

    'Clear the Clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your macro in the question?

Comment: The macro is too long to post. Just remember the column values are set with a hard coded value depending on the column's heading.

Comment: Can't answer the question but I know it cheesed me off when I upgraded from 2010 to 2016 and suddenly found all my workbooks had had their (manually assigned, not macro assigned) column widths shrunk by about 0.11 (e.g. from 2 to 1.89, and from 3 to 2.89).  I still haven't finished converting them back again.  Grrrr!

Comment: Robin, Here's part of the code. This is probably the root sub that's causing the problem. Yow, That is the exact same offset I am seeing. Many of my columns are going from 11 to 10.89 or 11.12.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It turns out it was the DPI setting after all. The user of the machine on which we were testing had changed the DPI settings in between the time we had checked the settings and actually tested.

When The DPI settings are changed, Display Settings> Advanced Display Settings> Advanced sizing of text and other items> Set a custom scaling level, the initial widths of excel columns in an excel spreadsheet change. I am not sure if this is a result of upgrading to windows 10, or the upgrade to office '16 (or both). Either way, we just have to make sure this setting is uniform on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with column widths being different on different computers, and it turned out that the computer where it looked "wrong" did not have a font installed (Meiryo UI), whereas the computer where I had worked on the file did have this font. Also, the image widths were affected -- any picture I had added from the "right" computer looked too narrow on the other one.